# Over com Group by

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Tenho uma query que utilizo para me retornar como extrato, acumulando os valores registro a registro:

```
SELECT  TOP (100) PERCENT Mes, Credito, Debito, Sum(Credito - Debito)  
over (ORDER BY Emp_id, Mes) AS Saldo , Emp_id
FROM     viewFluxo
ORDER BY Emp_id, Mes
```

Ocorre que o "over" com "group by" so funciona a partir do SQL2012.

Como posso construir uma outra consulta que retorne o mesmo resultado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A coluna saldo é acumulada registro a registro.

Comment: Pesquise na web por "running totals". Há vários artigos que explicam como implementar no SQL Server 2008.

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 3):

Calcule dinamicamente o saldo conforme a chave da linha corrente. Cuidado com o número de registros pois pode ficar lento se a quantidade de dados for muito grande.

Sumarize primeiro os meses por empresa com **GROUP BY** e depois faça o select com o calculo dinâmico.

```
WITH TB_Sumarizado as (
SELECT  Mes, Sum(Credito) as Credito, Sum(Debito) as Debito , Emp_id  
    FROM     viewFluxo 
    GROUP BY Mes , Emp_id
    ) 

Select TB_Sumarizado.Mes, TB_Sumarizado.Credito, TB_Sumarizado.Debito,
(Select Sum(b.Credito - b.Debito) from TB_Sumarizado b where b.Mes <= TB_Sumarizado.Mes AND b.Emp_id = TB_Sumarizado.Emp_id ) AS Saldo 
FROM TB_Sumarizado
```

Comment: Na primeira `query` que você sugeriu tem um `INNER JOIN` "solto". Na segunda tem um `AS` logo depois do `WITH` que não existe. Você não está considerando mais de uma empresa, como aparenta ser a modelagem proposta.

Comment: Tem razão, é que fiz os testes com outras tabelas. Já corrigi e coloquei o campo de Emp_id.

Comment: Ótimo. A segunda `query` funciona corretamente, mas a primeira ainda não funciona pra múltiplas empresas...

Comment: Retirei a query não utilizada para não confundir possíveis buscas sobre o assunto.

Comment: Tranquilo, dei +1, ficou boa sua solução.

Answer (score 3):

Através das Dicas resolvi deste modo, nos testes parece resultado correto:

```
SELECT c.mes,
       c.credito,
       c.debito,
       d.saldo,
       c.emp_id
  FROM viewfluxo AS c
       INNER JOIN (SELECT a.mes,
                          SUM(b.credito - b.debito) AS saldo,
                          a.emp_id
                     FROM viewfluxo AS a
                          INNER JOIN viewfluxo AS b ON a.mes >= b.mes
                    GROUP BY a.emp_id,
                             a.mes) AS d ON c.mes = d.mes
                                        AND c.emp_id = d.emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar `WITH` aninhado para obter a ordem e calcular os valores:

```
WITH sequencia AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r.emp_id ORDER BY r.mes) AS sequencia,
         r.mes,
         r.credito,
         r.debito,
         r.emp_id
    FROM viewFluxo r
),
saldo AS (
  SELECT s.sequencia,
         s.mes,
         s.credito,
         s.debito,
         s.emp_id,
         CAST((s.credito - s.debito) AS NUMERIC(15, 2)) AS saldo
    FROM sequencia s
   WHERE s.sequencia = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT s.sequencia,
         s.mes,
         s.credito,
         s.debito,
         s.emp_id,
         CAST((sal.saldo + (s.credito - s.debito)) AS NUMERIC(15, 2))
    FROM saldo sal
         INNER JOIN sequencia s ON s.sequencia = sal.sequencia + 1
                               AND s.emp_id = sal.emp_id
)
SELECT s.emp_id,
       s.mes,
       s.credito,
       s.debito,
       s.saldo
  FROM saldo s
 ORDER BY s.emp_id,
          s.mes
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

---

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4cb02/1).

---

Caso não queira utilizar `ROW_NUMBER` como forma de gerar uma sequência, você pode converter o mês em `DATE` e utiliza-lo para organizar os valores:

```
WITH saldo AS (
  SELECT vf.mes,
         vf.credito,
         vf.debito,
         vf.emp_id,
         CAST((vf.credito - vf.debito) AS NUMERIC(15, 2)) AS saldo
    FROM viewFluxo vf
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                      FROM viewFluxo vf2
                     WHERE vf2.emp_id = vf.emp_id
                       AND vf2.mes < vf.mes)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT vf.mes,
         vf.credito,
         vf.debito,
         vf.emp_id,
         CAST((sal.saldo + (vf.credito - vf.debito)) AS NUMERIC(15, 2))
    FROM saldo sal
         INNER JOIN viewFluxo vf ON CONVERT(DATE, vf.mes + '01', 120) = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CONVERT(DATE, sal.mes + '01', 120))
                                AND vf.emp_id = sal.emp_id
)
SELECT s.emp_id,
       s.mes,
       s.credito,
       s.debito,
       s.saldo
  FROM saldo s
 ORDER BY s.emp_id,
          s.mes
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

---

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4cb02/12).

---

Utilizei o seguinte script para criar e popular a tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE viewFluxo(mes       VARCHAR(6),
                       credito   NUMERIC(15, 2),
                       debito    NUMERIC(15, 2),
                       emp_id    VARCHAR(4));

INSERT INTO viewFluxo(mes, credito, debito, emp_id)
               VALUES('201708', 0,      5000,  '0001'),
                     ('201709', 123.25, 5000,  '0001'),
                     ('201710', 0,      10000, '0001'),
                     ('201711', 0,      10000, '0001'),
                     ('201712', 0,      10000, '0001'),
                     ('201801', 0,      10000, '0001'),
                     ('201802', 0,      10000, '0001'),
                     ('201803', 0,      10000, '0001'),
                     --
                     ('201708', 3600, 900,     '0002'),
                     ('201709', 3600, 1350.75, '0002'),
                     ('201710', 3600, 900,     '0002'),
                     ('201711', 3600, 2000,    '0002'),
                     ('201712', 3600, 750.25,  '0002'),
                     ('201801', 3600, 1009.9,  '0002'),
                     ('201802', 3600, 900,     '0002'),
                     ('201803', 3600, 900,     '0002'),
                     ('201804', 3600, 900,     '0002');
```